# Como puedo recorrer un array con ngFor anidados angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular, dom

seguramente dieran que es algo muy facil de hacer pero estoy tratando de recorre el array de datos de esta forma

```
<tr *ngFor="let list of listadoRangosPivot; let i = index">
    <td class="text-right">{{list.id_tercero_fk}}</td>
    <td>{{list.nombres_tercero}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let item of listadoRangosPivot; let j = index">{{ list.rangos.total[i,j]}}</td>  
</tr>
```

Este es el JSON con los datos que estoy tratande de recorrer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en respuesta esto es lo que trae a la tabla, si alguien ya pudo hacerlo agradecería su ayuda y concejo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionarlo cree un pipe y lo hice de esta forma

```js
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'keys' })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args: string[]): any {
        let keys = [];
        for (let key in value) {
            keys.push({ key: key, value: value[key] });
        }
        return keys;
    }
}
```

y tuve que hacer estos cambios en la tabla

```html
<table id="tableDeudasEdades" name="tableDeudasEdades" class="table" *ngIf="vistaPanelAcitvo==7">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="150">Identificacion</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
      <th *ngFor="let item of rangos" class="text-right">DE {{item.i}} A {{item.f}} DIAS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let keys  of listadoRangosPivot">
      <td>
        <strong>{{keys.id_tercero_fk}}</strong>
      </td>
      <td> {{keys.nombres_tercero}} </td>
      <td *ngFor="let key  of keys.rangos | keys" class="text-right">
        {{key.value | currency:$:'1.0-0'}}
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor qué puedes hacer es crear una propiedad computada y utilizarla en tu vista para tener más mantenible tu código.

```
const data = [
    {
        id_tercero_fk: "1234",
        nombres_tercero: "Maria perez perez",
        rangos: {
            name: [ "DE 1 A 10 DIAS", "DE 11 A 20 DIAS", "DE 21 A 20 DIAS" ],
            total: [ 4000000, 4000000, 0 ]
        }
    }
]

const items = data.map(item => ({
    id: item.id_tercero_fk || 0,
    customer: item.nombres_tercero || '',
    from1To10Days: item.rangos.total[0] || 0,
    from11To20Days: item.rangos.total[1] || 0,
    from21To20Days: item.rangos.total[2] || 0
}));

<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <td [class.text-right]="i === 0">{{ item }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Debí ser mas especifico con mi problema lo que estoy tratado de hacer es un pivot con angular, los rangos por días son dinámicos y puedo agregar o  quitar según mi necesidad para eso tengo un un formulario que filtra esa consulta.
Muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: ¿Tienes por cada item N totales de rango como de nombres de rango?

Comment: Si, son rangos por día puedo tener N rangos, es decir del 100 al 200 y del 201 al 300 u otros, si el numero de días entra en el rango pues nuestra el valor correspondiente sino lo deja en cero, lo que quiero es poder mostrar en una tabla el el total por rango (total: [ 4000000, 4000000, 0 ]) pero lo que hace es que me muestra el primero y me llena todos con ese primer registro por eso la idea de poder recorrer el array de esta for ma [x,y] por al parecer angular no lo permite asi de facil

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo así:

```
<tr *ngFor="let list of listadoRangosPivot; let i = index">
<td class="text-right">{{list.id_tercero_fk}}</td>
<td>{{list.nombres_tercero}}</td>
<td *ngFor="let item of list.rangos; let j = index">{{ item.total[0]}}</td>
```